# “ionic start myProject” is filling the project root with node aux files

Tags: cordova, ionic2

Windows10 x64

VisualStudio 2015

Ionic v 2.2.1

Cordova v 6.5.0

NodeJS v 6.10.0

"ionic start myProject" starts restoring packages and fills the project root with all these .cmd files:

```
09/03/2017 00:10 29 .bowerrc
09/03/2017 00:10 242 .editorconfig
09/03/2017 00:10 138 .gitignore
09/03/2017 00:13 321 bower
09/03/2017 00:13 198 bower.cmd
09/03/2017 00:10 118 bower.json
09/03/2017 00:13 335 cleancss
09/03/2017 00:13 212 cleancss.cmd
09/03/2017 00:14 962 config.xml
09/03/2017 00:13 333 dateformat
.....
09/03/2017 00:13 325 semver
09/03/2017 00:13 202 semver.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 323 shjs
09/03/2017 00:13 200 shjs.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 331 sshpk-conv
09/03/2017 00:13 208 sshpk-conv.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 331 sshpk-sign
09/03/2017 00:13 208 sshpk-sign.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 335 sshpk-verify
09/03/2017 00:13 212 sshpk-verify.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 323 strip-bom
09/03/2017 00:13 200 strip-bom.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 329 strip-indent
09/03/2017 00:13 206 strip-indent.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 323 user-home
09/03/2017 00:13 200 user-home.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 317 uuid
09/03/2017 00:13 194 uuid.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 321 which
09/03/2017 00:13 198 which.cmd
09/03/2017 00:13 327 window-size
09/03/2017 00:13 204 window-size.cmd
03/2017 00:14 www
```

I've reinstalled node, cordova and ionic twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found it.
It's all about the npm configuration files. 
Even you have one global for all npm modules -the same that ionic uses to create the project- the package restore process will use another configuration file.